# Vba excel Formula Computation?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

---

Hi all,i am new to vba please help me. I have a table like shown. The Days column is a formula column. the formula is simple it is the difference of **Actual Date** and **Date**. But the **Actual Date**is present in another sheet (Sheet2) at Range("D5"). How to assign this formula programatically. I tried with `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E10").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Value & "-Sheet1!RC[-1]"` and `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I6:I10").FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet2!R[5]C[4]Sheet1!RC[-1]"` unfornately both are giving wrong values. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DATEDIF](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx) function to calculate the difference between two dates:

```
=DATEDIF(Sheet2!D5,Sheet1!E2,"D")
```

You will have to copy and modify this formula for the column, as this should work for the first cell.

**Update:**

Using VBA, you can use the below, which should work with your above dataset:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E10").FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEDIF(""" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5") & """,Sheet1!RC[-1],""D"")"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the formula is from another sheet you can still reference the data on the current sheet.

**Using R1C1 with formula:**

Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=Today() - R[0]C[-1]"

**Adding just the number to the spreadsheet:**

Range("E2").Value = DateDiff("d", Range("D2"), Now())

UPDATE:

For more than one value:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E10").FormulaR1C1 = "=Today() - R[0]C[-1]"
```

Comment: thanks for quick response...i will be having thousands of rows so looping through all rows and assigning value is bit time consuming process. Because i have more than 10 columns of this type. Any other idea?

Comment: I have changed Formula like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E10").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Value & " - R[0]C[-1]"` but it is giving wrong output.

Comment: do you need the value or formula to be on the spreadsheet? Value is much more efficient